# Content Filter based on Heirarchical Taxonomies

Tags: ajax, nodes, views

I have one taxonomy named "Project Parameters" with hierarchical select and another taxonomy names "Project Sub Parameters" with hierarchical select.

I Want to filter the content with those taxonomies like on selection of Project parameter display its sub parameters and click on sub parameters with ajax call i need content filter

I Had created view and with contextual filter i achieve that but that load the page. I want to do same functionality with ajax only, No page reload.

Is it Possible? Please Help Me.. I am stuck since last 2 days.

Comment: Just want to make sure you have tried Use Ajax: Yes  under Advance configuration of views.

Comment: Yes i had tried ajax under advance configuration but not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create views for

- Project parameters
- Project sub parameters with contexual filter of project parameter taxonomy id with filter criteria
- Content view with contexual filter of project sub parameters taxonomy id.

After Create these views you can call ajax api and pass those conexutal filter on ajax for particular view like,

```
$view = views_get_view('viewname'); //viewname is the view machine name
$view->set_display("block_1"); //block_1 is the view display name
$view->set_arguments($tid); //$tid is the argument to pass
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$content = $view->render();
```

I got the success by this way.

Hope this answer help somebody.